# How to update list item when using paging library and custom datasource?

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-paging

I am using paging library and everything is working good when I am directly returning `DataSource.Factory<Int, Data>` from Dao and then setting my paged list like this

`pagedList = LivePagedListBuilder(dao().getAllData(), config).build()`

When I click on my list item, it changes, updates the room database and with paging automatically updates the UI. But I need to use a custom data source. So I created one and now I am setting my paged list like this

`pagedList = LivePagedListBuilder(customDatasourceFactory, config).build()`.

The problem is that now when I update a row in my room table, the UI is not automatically updated. I am also using `invalidate()` when my dataset is changed. But in this case when I want to update only a single item, I can not use it, because my positional datasource then loads the first page and when I am in the middle of my list, alter list item, it jumps to the top.

So basically what I want is to implement the same behaviour that I had when I was returning directly Datasource Factory from Dao, but now with my own datasource.

Comment: I think you need to look into your DiffUtil implementation.

Comment: @tomas were you able to find a solution?